# How can i modify a byte array?

Tags: python, arrays

I was reading about bytes and byte array's. I read that byte arrays mutable types!
so, when i am trying to modify it i am getting an error saying `integer is required` Am i missing something here? The following is my code and the error

```
z=bytearray("hello world","utf-8")
z[0] ="H"
```

i got the following error

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 z[0]="H"
>
> TypeError: an integer is required

Comment: Did you mean `z[0] = ord('H')`?

Comment: Oh!, so, i have to give the ascii value? @Norrius

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the docs say:

> The bytearray type is a mutable sequence of **integers** in the range 0 <= x < 256.

The reason you can create it with a string as each character is converted to its ASCII **integer** value. So when assigning `'H'` you actually mean to assign `72`.

If you want to be able to assign chars, then just pass each one into `ord()` first.

Comment: so, how would i modify it to have UTF-8 characters?

Comment: @Kalyan ASCII is a subset of Unicode encodings, so it is already UTF-8.

Comment: @Kalyan Don't use a `bytearray`! Use a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list)

Comment: @JoeIddon, i was just learning about bytearray's so, i was trying to use it. But, from what you mentioned, i cant modify the string to have a utf-8 character right?

Comment: @Kalyan It is not a string that it is being modified. It is a `bytearray`. If you know from C or similar, an array is (normally) a sequence of *integers* that can be indexed. A `string` is normally seen in higher-level languages but at the fundamental level, it is an array of *integers* representing the ASCII characters (a UTF-8 subset). So if you want a string where you can change the characters by index, you would be better of with a `list` of individual characters e.g: `list("hello there")` which gives `['h', 'e', 'l', ...]` so then you can modify chars by index as lists are mutable.

Comment: @Kalyan Oh and when you want to convert that back to a `string` (for prettier printing etc.) then you can use the `join` method on an empty string: `''.join(lst)`.

Comment: @JoeIddon  Part of the problem here is that the OP did not assign a character, 'H', but rather a string "H".  If he had used a character, it's possible that the compiler would have promoted the character to an int.