# Difficulty with assigning values to bytearrays in Python without using integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to work with byte buffers in Python. The way I tried to go about it was to start with a zero-filled `bytearray`:

```
>>> d=bytearray(3)
>>> d
bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00')
```

So far so good. I had tried to use `bytes`, but the documentation told me these would not be mutable. However, `bytearrays` should support mutable operations. Let's say I'm building some low-level fixed-sized packet, zero-padded, and I need to set the first bytes for my header. I try, because I'm lazy:

```
>>> d[0:1] = b'\x01\x01'
>>> d
bytearray(b'\x01\x01\x00\x00')
```

What gives? I started with a zero-filled bytearray precisely because I needed to *keep the size constant*. With the slicing I used, the answer doesn't even make sense: at worst, I expected the assignment of the two bytes to occur in both positions [0,1], adding two extra bytes to the total. Adding one extra byte just sounds nonsensical. Anyway...

Now, sure, let me try to assign each byte individually like a proper person...

```
>>> d[0] = b'\x01'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'bytes' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I give up. I'm certainly not going to be working in both bytes and integers at the same time to fix this (and why was that not a problem in the previous example?). And I can't find any meaningful resource on the internet on "bytearray assignments" (the closest was a Wikiversity article which had an empty Assignments section).

Is there a sane way to manipulate bytearrays in Python? Thank you!

*Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32*

Comment: `d[0:1] = b'\x01\x01'` will always work that way with built-in slicing, silce notation is *non inclusive*. Bytearrays are mutable, and can re-size. You want `d[0:2] = b'\x01\x01'` Note, `bytearray` objects require `int` objects for assignment (regular and slice-based). Because slice-assigning with another bytes objects will produce ints, note `list(b'\x01')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i modify a byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50679664/how-can-i-modify-a-byte-array)

Comment: In other words, you need to do `d[0] = 1`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ok, I'm glad that can work then, since it will make my work easier. Can I use d[0:1] for single byte assignments then?

Comment: @RicardoM. yeah, try it.

Comment: @metatoaster As I stated in the question, I'm certainly not going to be working in both bytes and integers at the same time, so the question you cited just rephrases the Python traceback - "work with integers". I am asking for a non-integer conversion way of doing the assignments.

Comment: You will need to cast your singular assignment to an integer with `ord` as per the linked question.  If you must do it that specific way, you need to do `d[0] = ord(b'\x01')` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @juanpa.arrivillaga's comment above.

You can work with bytes in `bytearray` if you use *non-inclusive** slice assignments, such that:

```
d[0:1] = b'\x01' # Single byte assignment
d[0:2] = b'\x01\x01' # Multiple byte assignments
```

This type of byte assignment will implicitly produce the integers needed to assign to the `bytearray`, instead of e.g. d[0]. If the length of the slice is smaller than the assignment, the array will grow as in my example.

(*that's just the way to slice in Python, the emphasis is just because I forgot about it in the question.)